# It is only uploading first row's file input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a application which you can access [here](https://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable2.php). If you open the application please click on the "Add" button a couple of times. This will add a new row into a table below. In each table row there is an AJAX file uploader.

Now the problem is that if I click on the "Upload" button in any row except the first row, then the uploading only happens in the first row so it is only uploading the first file input only.

Why is it doing this and how can I get it so that when then the user clicks the "Upload" button, the file input within that row of the "Upload" button is uploaded and not the first row being uploaded?

Below is the full code where it appends the file AJAX file uploaded in each table row:

```
function insertQuestion(form) {   

    var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
    var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
    var $image = $("<td class='image'></td>"); 


    var $fileImage = $("<form action='upload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target' onsubmit='startUpload();' >" + 
    "<p id='f1_upload_process' align='center'>Loading...<br/><img src='Images/loader.gif' /><br/></p><p id='f1_upload_form' align='center'><br/><label>" + 
    "File: <input name='fileImage' type='file' class='fileImage' /></label><br/><label><input type='submit' name='submitBtn' class='sbtn' value='Upload' /></label>" +
    "</p> <iframe id='upload_target' name='upload_target' src='#' style='width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;'></iframe></form>");

    $image.append($fileImage);

    $tr.append($image);  
    $tbody.append($tr); 

}

function startUpload(){
      document.getElementById('f1_upload_process').style.visibility = 'visible';
      document.getElementById('f1_upload_form').style.visibility = 'hidden';
      return true;
}

function stopUpload(success){
      var result = '';
      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span class="msg">The file was uploaded successfully!<\/span><br/><br/>';
      }
      else {
         result = '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!<\/span><br/><br/>';
      }
      document.getElementById('f1_upload_process').style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.getElementById('f1_upload_form').innerHTML = result + '<label>File: <input name="fileImage" type="file"/><\/label><label><input type="submit" name="submitBtn" class="sbtn" value="Upload" /><\/label>';
      document.getElementById('f1_upload_form').style.visibility = 'visible';      
      return true;   
}
```

UPDATE:

Current Code:

```
 var $fileImage = $("<form action='upload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target' onsubmit='startUpload(this);' >" + 
    "<p class='f1_upload_process' align='center'>Loading...<br/><img src='Images/loader.gif' /><br/></p><p class='f1_upload_form' align='center'><br/><label>" + 
    "File: <input name='fileImage' type='file' class='fileImage' /></label><br/><label><input type='submit' name='submitBtn' class='sbtn' value='Upload' /></label>" +
    "</p> <iframe class='upload_target' name='upload_target' src='#' style='wclassth:0;height:0;border:0px solclass #fff;'></iframe></form>");

function stopUpload(success, source_form){
      var result = '';
      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span class="msg">The file was uploaded successfully!<\/span><br/><br/>';
      }
      else {
         result = '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!<\/span><br/><br/>';
      }
      $(source_form).find('.f1_upload_process').style.visibility = 'hidden';
      $(source_form).find('.f1_upload_form').innerHTML = result + '<label>File: <input name="fileImage" type="file"/><\/label><label><input type="submit" name="submitBtn" class="sbtn" value="Upload" /><\/label>';
      $(source_form).find('.f1_upload_form').style.visibility = 'visible';      
      return true;   
}
```

Why am I getting an error on this line below:

```
$(source_form).find('.f1_upload_form').style.visibility = 'visible';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the full cose, your problem seems to be that you are working with ID's, which must be unique within one document. If several elements are using the same ID, in the best case a browser will use the first one (which it does here), in the worst case nothing will work.

When adding a new upload form, you have to give the elements in it unique ID's. You could do that simply by attaching a counting variable to `window`, e.g.

```
$(document).ready( function(){ window.formCount=0; } );
```

You could then add that number to the ID of the newly added form.

Apart from this, by using the `this` variable, you can carry a reference to the correct form through, e.g. like `onsubmit='startUpload(this);'` as well as `function startUpload(f){...`
You should then be able to access things within the form using `$(f).find(...)`.

There are many ways to make this work and solve the issue of multiple ID's. What I would do: `var $fileImage = $("<form action...` In this form where it says `id` I would instead use `class`. Then as above, change the onsubmit (in the same line) by adding "this" to its brackets. Then change the function startUpload as here:

```
function startUpload(source_form){
  $(source_form).find('.f1_upload_process').css('visibility','visible');
  $(source_form).find('.f1_upload_form').css('visibility','hidden');
  return true;
}
```

You have to do the same thing for other functions where you want to access something inside the form that is sending a file. Pass a reference to the form to the function using `this` in the function call's brackets, then access things inside the form as I showed above.

Comment: I know I am asking a lot but can you provide a sample of your code with the code I have in the question so I can see what you mean? I am struggling to know what you mean.

Comment: Hi, Can I just ask you is source_form the class you gave in the form tag? I want to know where the function StopUpload, in the brackets should it be (success, source_form)?

Comment: source_form is a variable name used to reference whatever is passed to the function `startUpload` in the brackets when it is called. I suggest you have a read through the [W3Schools JS Functions tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp).

Comment: Last question, I am getting an undefined error in this line in the function `stopUpload(success, source_form)`:       $(source_form).find('.f1_upload_process').style.visibility = 'hidden';. I have changed all of the id's to class but why am I getting this error? I update current code I now have below my question:

Comment: `$(source_form).find('.f1_upload_form').innerHTML` won't work because using the $ makes this into a jQuery-object, which does not have an innerHTML. You can instead use `$(source_form).find('.f1_upload_form').html(result + '<label..(etc)../label>');`

Comment: Thanks, I figured out that I need to use .css instead of .style but thanks for the .html... part.